# Can't install Apache web agent for OpenAM implementation

Tags: windows, apache, tomcat, configuration, openam

I have previously installed a J2EE policy agent and implemented SSO with it. Now I was trying to do the same with a web policy agent, but I am stuck. When I am trying to install the Apache22 web agent, I am being asked to provide some inputs. The second input is the URL of the OpenAM server. In my case, that is http://openam.example.com:9080/openIdp2 . But whenever I enter this value, the installation gets stuck. I have taken the following steps:

1. I have ensured that the openAM server is up and running.
2. I have created a centralized web agent in the openAM server.
3. I have installed OpenSSL and included the libeay32.dll, ssleay32.dll files in the agent/lib folder( I don’t have the ‘dll files missing’ error)
4. I have added the agent/lib folder in the environment variable path.

I have done all this and yet I am getting nowhere. I had used these same steps when I had configured the J2EE agent earlier. The OpenAM server is deployed in Tomcat on my local machine.

**This is the configuration I am using:**

1. Http server: Apache 2.2
2. Web Policy Agent: 
   i)Release: 4.0.0 
   ii)Platform: Apache 2.2
3. OS: Windows 10 64 bit

When I tried installing using the ‘silent’ option, I was asked to provide all the input. I did that and now the console is just stuck with the ‘Validating…’ message. It has been in that way for some time. The installation doesn’t stop, it just freezes. 
Can you tell me what I might be doing wrong? 
Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a while back and was advised to step-back to the 3.3.4 Agent.  Since there were no features I needed in 4.0 that were not in 3.3 I did and have not looked back.  Also, consider that the latest agent available is 4.0.1.  So either go back to 3.3.4 or consider trying 4.0.1.